# How to plot Counter object in horizontal bar chart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, counter

I have a Counter object. I'd like to plot a horizontal bar chart like this http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barh_demo.html

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This is the example from the page you mentioned modified to use a counter object:

```
 """
Simple demo of a horizontal bar chart.
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Counter data, counter is your counter object
keys = counter.keys()
y_pos = np.arange(len(keys))
# get the counts for each key, assuming the values are numerical
performance = [counter[k] for k in keys]
# not sure if you want this :S
error = np.random.rand(len(keys))

plt.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center', alpha=0.4)
plt.yticks(y_pos, keys)
plt.xlabel('Counts per key')
plt.title('How fast do you want to go today?')

plt.show()
```

Comment: What if you wanted the keys sorted on the value?